# Suggest me a good php-fpm configuartion

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I am configuring a server for a friend.The server has the following specs

```
8GB RAM 
Quad Core processor 
1 TB HDD 
100 mbps port
```

However all php files are loadking very slowly.I did a speedtest and server takes 16 secs to Load FIRST byte.I strongly believe its my php-fpm configuration.Server uses nginx and php only , no mysql etc...

My current php-fpm configuration

```
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 10
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 35
```

Server load and ram usage are perfectly fine

Please suggest me a good configuration for this server

---

**UPDATE:**

This configuration works fine

```
pm.max_children = 20
pm.start_servers = 7
pm.min_spare_servers = 5
pm.max_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_requests = 100
```

The problem with first byte load time is solved.However after like 15-20 hours First byte load time increase gradually. I have to reload php-fpm to get small load time 
Based on my conf above what i modify to it so that first byte load time remain small and i don't have to restart it:P

UPDATE 2:
Before i restarted the php-fpm 
Time to load first byte: 1.5 sec
Total page load time :3.0 sec
Time after i restart php-fpm 
Time to load first byte: 0.3 sec
Total page load time :1.5 sec

This clearly shows its a matter of php-fpm configuration , not of slow code

Answer (score 3):

Way too many workers! Use APC to speed up your code and I fully agree with @Martin Fjordvald that slow code is simply slow code. You could for instance post your index.php and we could help you find the bottleneck.

You can have a look at my personal configuration at [GitHub](https://github.com/Fleshgrinder/php5). Last load test with a Drupal installation showed loading times of around 120 ms.

Create a new cronjob via `crontab -e` and put the following into the file:

```
# Simple reload every hour.
@hourly /etc/init.d/php5-fpm reload

# And restart at midnight.
@daily /etc/init.d/php5-fpm restart
```

Comment: Thanks so much......now site load fast.Need to check how server performs with your configuration

Comment: I already use APC

Comment: Check my updated post

Comment: Actually I reload php-fpm every hour and restart it every day via a cronjob. This helps to keep it perfectly stable. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks ......However i though that there must be some way to fix it.However i guess no one has solution so i install the cron job

Answer (score 0):

Slow code is slow code and your server configuration cannot do anything about it. The only case that can cause slow speed is if you have so much traffic that your requests have to wait for a process to become available.

Since you're using PHP-FPM enable the slow log and figure out why your code is slow.

Comment: The code is not that slow , page was loading in 1-2 sec when no user was downloading , now when 10-12 users donload , php pages takes much time to load .HTML pages are load almost instantly

Comment: 1-2 seconds is still slow, add in a blocking issue and 10-12 users will cause huge problems. Just enable the damn slow log instead of fumbling around blindly in the dark.

Comment: Check my post , i updated it

Comment: So because restarting PHP often fixes the slow code issue it's not a PHP issue but a php-fpm configuration issue? That logic is severely flawed.

Comment: Several site uses this script and non have this problem-most are on apache